# Probability cards

Tags: probability

From a standard deck of 52 cards you deal cards without replacement until you get 2 aces. the question is what is the Probability distribution for the number 2 cards that were dealt?

my attempt is that given the number of card that were dealt -n ,  x which is the number of 2's distributes HG(52,4,n) then i tried to use the law of total probability but i wasnt sure how to find the probability n=i. I know that the number of cards until the first ace distributes uniformly and so is the second given the number of card until the first ace but I am not sure how to put it all together

Comment: Another question, since this is not a 'do my homework for free' service, is what effort have you made in attempting to answer the previous question on your own?

Comment: my attempt is that given the number of card that were dealt -n ,  x which is the number of 2's distributes HG(52,4,n) then i tried to use the law of total probability but i wasnt sure how to find the probability n=i. I know that the number of cards until the first ace distributes uniformly and so is the second given the number of card until the first ace but I am not sure how to put it all together

Comment: Add it to the question please.

Comment: Also, what does "the number 2 cards that were dealt" mean???

Comment: means how many 2's were dealt until that second ace